# MySQL pass parents field to subquery without using JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sequelize.js

I need to pass a field to a subquery instead of using a JOIN but most examples online only show how to do this using joins.

The scenario is the following:

I have a table of Accounts on the system.
Each account can perform Tasks, which can fail.
I want to get a list of Accounts, with a custom column 'status' which is -1 if the last two Tasks failed.

E.g.

```
SELECT Account.id, (

    CASE WHEN (

       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (

           SELECT id, status FROM Task
           WHERE Task.AccountId = Account.id // <-- Cannot access Account.id here
           HAVING status < 0 // <-- only select failed tasks
           ORDER BY id DESC
           LIMIT 2
       ) as t1)

    ) < 2 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END

) as `status` FROM Account;
```

Computing status for each Task is a heavy query (not shown above), so I only want to be computing the status for tasks that belong to the queried accounts.

I've tried using user variables, replacing Account.id with @AccountId, but I don't think one can use them in a subquery like this.

I cannot use a JOIN on the main Account table because I am using sequelize. However I could use JOINs in a subquery should that help.

Comment: I don't see an order by in your sub query.

Comment: @SalmanA sorry, have added.

Comment: Your code is not doing what you want.  The `HAVING` clause is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution I could think of (it *is* possible to use joins though). Works for last two rows:

```
SELECT Account.id, (
    SELECT status
    FROM Task
    WHERE Task.AccountId = Account.id
    ORDER BY Task.Id DESC
    LIMIT 0, 1
) + (
    SELECT status
    FROM Task
    WHERE Task.AccountId = Account.id
    ORDER BY Task.Id DESC
    LIMIT 1, 1
) AS sum_of_last_two
FROM Account
```

The result would be -2, -1 or 0 etc which could be tested inside `CASE`. You might want to wrap each sub-query inside `COALESCE((...), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

For your particular problem, you can express this using separate queries for each status you want to check:

```
select a.*,
       (case when (select t.status
                   from task t
                   where t.AccountId = a.id
                   order by t.id desc
                   limit 1
                  ) = -1 and
                  (select t.status
                   from task t
                   where t.AccountId = a.id
                   order by t.id desc
                   limit 1 offset 1
                  ) = -1
             then 1 else -1
         end)                  
from accounts a;
```

For performance, you want an index on `task(accountid, id, status)`.